# Issue with session timeout

Tags: php, session, timeout, session-timeout

When a user logged in, after some time the session times out and redirects to the home page.

Does anyone know why this may be occurring?

Following code is used for logout:

```
if($user->isLogged())
{
    $user->logout();
    $session->set('error','Successfully Logged Out');
    $response->redirect('index.php');
}

function logout() {     
     $this->session->delete('user_id');
     $this->data = array();
}

function isLogged() {
    return !empty($this->data);
}
```

Is there any way for increasing session time?

Comment: Check http://lt.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-maxlifetime

Comment: @Natasha: Your question is nearly a year old. How did you solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

```
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', '28800');
```